# "could not find driver" error while connection yii2 application with sql server

Tags: php, yii, yii2, xampp, php-extension

I am trying to connect my yii2 basic application with sql server. But i am getting error

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

could not find driver
```

Here is my connection credentials

```
'sqlserver' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=localhost;dbname=TestDatabase',
            'username' => 'sa',
            'password' => 'test123',
            'schemaMap' => [
                'sqlsrv'=> [
                  'class'=>'yii\db\mssql\Schema',
                  //'defaultSchema' => 'public' //specify your schema here
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

I found that sql server drivers were missing in xampp so i added These dll files
php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

and added this code in php.ini `extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll`

but still getting same error

What could be the solution?

Comment: Did you restart apache server?

Answer (score 0):

I m also getting same error

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

Could not find driver

But I m able connect  using simple php code.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the php drivers for the database you want to use. I supopse its MS SQL, here you have the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Comment: I already added those drivers php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll i have also mentioned it in my question

Comment: Ok, thats right. Maybe try installing the driver provided by Microsoft. Also does XAMPP has one php.ini file or two (one for CLI other for web?) I ma not sure how it works in Windows.